# QT - Adding widgets to horizontal layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

i have an horizontal layout and i am adding widgets by using

```
ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(label);
```

But adding strategy is not what i want. For example, when i add items, it first puts the start, then puts at the end and keep putting from end.

[image: adding 3 widgets]

[image: keep adding]

But, what i want is that, when i add widget to layout, it should be put next to the previous widget. like that ,
[image: what i want]

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 16):

Add a stretcher to it after you have added all the widgets.

```
ui->horizontalLayout->addStretch();
```

will do.

Comment: That seems very strange to me. You added it *after* adding the widgets, right?

Comment: yeap. after for loop is finished (after all widgets are added), i add the `ui->horizontalLayout->addStretch();`

Answer (score 9):

You can add a [spacer item](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html), either on the outside of your horizontal layout, or inside your horizontal layout. If you add the spacer item inside the horizontal layout, you have to make sure you add your label widgets before the spacer item. Use the [insertWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) function to add your labels in this case.

Or you can add the spaceritem to the end of your horizontal layout after you've added your label widgets.

Here is an example:

```
QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
ui->verticalLayout->addLayout(hlayout);
QSpacerItem *item = new QSpacerItem(1,1, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
hlayout->addSpacerItem(item);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("NOTE");
    hlayout->insertWidget(i, label);
}
```

Comment: Do you have more specific example how to use spacer item?

Comment: @abby I modified my answer and added an example.

Comment: it adds like the second picture i put in the question. But i want not to have any space between notes like third picture.

Comment: @abby That shouldn't happen if you add your spacer item in the correct place with the correct size policies. Does it make any difference if you add the spacer item?

Answer (score 5):

`setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);` should do the trick. Also you can use this with:
 `setSpacing(0);setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);` 
to remove extra space between widgets.